# Javascript : How do I map gps coordinates to an image

Tags: javascript, html, gps

I am a newbie to programming and JavaScript. I've been working on an app for an Android tablet that can open an image file with a single click. Now I have an image that shows a map of my neighbourhood. I want my GPS location to be shown on this image with and without a wireless network connection. How do I do this? I am using the Jo framework because another guy who was working on the app used it, although I'm not sure why.

This code gives me an error as "ReferenceError: sp is not defined"
//Shows a list of available maps

```
var MapsCard = {
cardName: "mapsCard",



init: function () {
    "use strict";
    /*jslint newcap: true */
    joCache.set(this.cardName, function () {
        this.card = new joCard(new joFlexcol([
        this.title = new joTitle("Maps"),   
        //fancy toggle button
        new joLabel("GPS"),
        new joToggle(("isActive")),
        //Select maps dropdown
       this.dropdownlist = new joSelect([ "map1", "map2"]),
        ]));
        // respond to the change event
       this.dropdownlist.selectEvent.subscribe(this.openmaps, this);
       return this.card;
    }.bind(this));
},

openmaps: function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log("Loading picture ........" + value);
    //For different value load different maps.
    if(value == 0) {
        var win1 = window.open('');
        var img1 = win1.document.createElement("img");
        img1.src = "image1.png";
        win1.document.body.appendChild(img1);
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sp);
                        console.log("navigator.geolocation Works");
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported");
                }
             }  
    if(value == 1) {
        var win2 = window.open('');
        var img2 = win2.document.createElement("img");
        img2.src = "image2.png";
        win2.document.body.appendChild(img2);

    }
},

    sp: function(position) {
            //console.log(position.coords.latitude);
            //console.log(position.coords.longitude);
            console.log("Works....");
    },      

activate: function () {
    "use strict";
    this.active = true;
    },

deactivate: function () {
        "use strict";
            this.active = false;
    },
```

};

Comment: always post question with some code to show your efforts

Comment: You are going to have to find a way to include GPS coordinates in your image if you want to overlay GPS coordinates. You could probably do this using the latitude and longitude of the points in the corner of the image to interpolate the rest of the points. That said, this is a pretty broad question. Adding more detail and examples of the code that you already have will help get a more useful answer.

Comment: @richerlariviere Stop offending newbie strangers on the Internet. Shoo!

Comment: I deleted my post. I agree with you this wasn't appropriate. But let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick tutorial to get the GPS position:
[HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

You basically make a call like this:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

To put the lat/lon point on top of an image, you'll have to know the lat/lon of each corner of the image and then do some math.  Unless you're using some geospatial framework such as Google Maps API or OpenLayers, in which case the math can be done for you.

Comment: Thanks. :) I already tried out the tutorial before posting the question. I get a ReferenceError: sp is not defined. I have added the code now.

Comment: Try calling this.sp instead of just sp

    `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.sp);`